# Webcam recorded video play doesn't show time flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video, flash-media-server

I am Recording Video using webcam in my flex application using FMS. and publish that video as a

`ns.publish("mp4:"+FILENAME+".mp4","record");`

now i am trying to play that video directly which is stream , click on play button

`ns.play("mp4:"+FILENAME +".mp4");`

video is playing fine but using timer i am trying to display time it doesn't show. I debug my code so it's show error like **Error #1069: Property onMetaData not found on flash.net.NetStream and there is no default value.**

with same code i am trying to play video by giving static video url the it will show time.

```
ns.play("filename.mp4");
```

I am using **NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS** EventListener of netstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define specific client in order to use this: [http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event:onMetaData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event%3aonMetaData)

It's property of that client that you've assigned, not the NetStream itself.

I'll copy some of the docs so you can get a quick sample:

```
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
ns.client = {};
ns.client.onMetaData = ns_onMetaData;

video.attachNetStream(ns);
ns.play("http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/video/cuepoints.flv");


function ns_onMetaData(item:Object):void {
    trace("metaData");
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: And if i play this type of static video then it's play But when i try to play same video after streaming using fms at that time this thing happens

Comment: Ohh Ok but you give Way for that. Now it's work. thank You so Much for answer.